# Salesforce Custom label for lightning component does not kick off localization

Tags: lightning, managed-package, customlabel, lightning-out, localization

We have managed package with lightning component hosted in VF page via lightning out .Localization does not kick off for non-english user .This works perfectly fine in scratch org but not with the release build in production.The button using label looks like following :

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="{!$Label.c.labelName}"/>

Comment: Why do you have the `.c`? This is not required as far as I know.

Comment: @JefersonChaves This is required if we want to use custom label in lightning component : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm .

Comment: Does given user has non-english language? Is target language activated in translation workbench? Are translations deployed for labels?

Comment: @kurunve Yes the user is non-english user. We don't want to activate translation workbench in customer's org and also activating that sometimes translation kicks off sometime it does not so very unpredictable work around .  Translation files are deployed for labels .

Comment: It will not work with disabled translation workbench

Comment: @kurunve is that recommended by salesforce anywhere to activation of translation workbench is must that we can reference to ? I saw this work around is very unpredictable and does not work always .

Comment: I can't imagine translations working *without* translation workbench being enabled. Not only that, but you should also add the languages you need to support in Translation Workbench. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: I guess you should use `namespace` instead of `c`. Your scratch orgs should have the namespace, so, potentially no problem there.

Comment: @JefersonChaves namespace is not the issue as I am able to see the data of English label and also translation kicks of inconsistently when translation workbench is turned on .

Answer (score 0):

After activating translation workbench and adding the specific language as active kick off the translation.